# Unity3D Send AudioClip Through Whatsapp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an app feature to be able to pass the sounds that I have in my app to whatsapp. I've made some progress but I am stuck at getting byte array of an AudioClip.

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRs7L.png)

So I need to get the audioclip from the resources folder and write it to the path I gave, and then send it to whatsapp.

This gets an error

FormatException: Invalid length.
System.Convert.FromBase64String (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Convert.cs:146)

```
void sendProccess()
    {
        string s = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Bava").ToString();

        byte[] dataToSave = System.Convert.FromBase64String(s);

        string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".mp3");

        File.WriteAllBytes(destination, dataToSave);


        if (!Application.isEditor)
        {
            //instantiate the class Intent
            AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
            AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

            //instantiate the class Uri
            AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + destination);

            //call putExtra with the uri object of the file
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "audio/mp3");

            //instantiate the class UnityPlayer
            AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

            //instantiate the object currentActivity
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

            //call the activity with our Intent
            currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... Your question is `How to convert audio into Base64?`. Also put your code into the question, not a image.

Comment: Yes, thats the part I am having hard time, I added the code, sorry I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following line -

```
string s = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Bava").ToString();
```

The `ToString` method [returns the name of the object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.ToString.html).

You should use [`AudioClip.GetData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html) method to get raw data from audio clip -

```
AudioClip clip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Bava")
float[] samples = new float[clip.samples * clip.channels];
clip.GetData(samples, 0);
```

Then you can convert the `samples` array to its byte representation using BinaryWriter or BitConverter for further use.

Answer (score 0):

this work perfectly for me

```
 Application.OpenURL("whatsapp://send?phone=9999878653&text=[hello]");
```